# Laravel 5 500 internal error when using Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Hello !

I'm a beginner with Laravel. I wanted to experiment a little, so I made a basic controller using make:controller and started playing in its index() function. I simply wrote this :

```
return "Hello - ".Request::ip()." - ".Input::get('id');
```

And get a 500 internal server error when calling to the relevant route

```
mysite.com/public/emails?id=1
```

It works if I take out Request::ip() though, showing Hello - 1 without any problem.

The route :

```
Route::get('emails', 'EmailsController@index');
```

The includes at the beginning of the controller :

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \Input;
```

I would like to know 2 things :

- Why is that error popping ? I saw a lot of tutorials using this without any problem
- How can I debug efficiently in that sort of case ? There is nothing in the log @storage/logs/ and the page displays nothing as well.

Thanks ahead !!

Comment: also remember to check apache logs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass an `Request` object in the `index` method like so:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return $request->ip;
}
```

It's the way Laravel 5 changed. In Laravel 4 your code should work. They kind of separated it to make it more readable.

This is much cleaner and more OOP style. If you want to make your code more OO(Object Oriented) then use this.

And I think it's a good practice to use this, because most of the **Laravel 5** developers are using this style.

Comment: Thanks, you were right ! Do you know about my second question how to debug that kind of stuff ?

Comment: do you enabled debugging mode in your `.env` file? If not, then set `APP_DEBUG=false` to `APP_DEBUG=true`.

the `.env` file is located in your root directory of your Laravel app.

Comment: Thanks, it was on true though :)